# Deleting photo from Photo Library using Photo framework

Tags: ios, swift, photo, phasset, phphotolibrary

I am writing a photo album app which can access the photo from the user's photo library, add filter, and delete photo. I used the Photo framework to delete an asset with `PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(assetToDelete)`. 
The class of asset here is `PHAsset`.

```
// Delete the photo from library    
@IBAction func deleteBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let assetToDelete = self.asset
        if let assetToDelete = assetToDelete
          {
            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(assetToDelete)
          })
        }
      }
```

But error happen here, "Argument type 'PHAsset' does not conform to expected type 'NSFastEnumeration'".

So I change the type of assetToDelete as Xcode recommended:

```
PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(assetToDelete as! NSFastEnumeration)
```

It still doesn't work, the error is shows that:

> Could not cast value of type 'PHAsset' to 'NSFastEnumeration'

Does anyone know how to deal with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The clue is in the name ‘assets’ plural - the API wants an array or any other collection type that conforms to NSFastEnumeration e.g Set

`PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets([assetToDelete] as NSArray)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phassetchangerequest/1624062-deleteassets

Comment: Declared: `func delete(_ assets: [PHAsset]) {... PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(assets) ...}`. It gives error `Argument type '[PHAsset]' does not conform to expected type 'NSFastEnumeration'`

Comment: Interesting. Tried casting `as NSArray` ?

Comment: yes, it works with casting. But `[assetToDelete]` you mentioned is `swift array`, not `NSArray`

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov The compiler "should" bridge the Swift array to NSArray automagically. Are you using Xcode 11? That might be a bug.

Comment: With NSArray, as exactly Mr Burton's answer says, works for me.

Comment: if not use let arrayToDelete = NSArray(object: lastAsset)

Comment: Just an FYI, this bridging no longer works for `PHAsset` arrays in latest Swift

Answer (score 5):

The more correct way would be to fetch from the library first:

```
let assetIdentifiers = assetsToDeleteFromDevice.map({ $0.localIdentifier })
let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: assetIdentifiers, options: nil)
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(assets)
})
```